# Not able to get output of select query

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am executing a simple select query on my trial instance of snowflake.
select * from schema_migrations;

I am getting the following error:
SQL compilation error: Object 'SCHEMA_MIGRATIONS' does not exist or not authorized.

The correct role, database and schema have been selected in the top right corner of the query box.
Attaching a [screenshot](https://easyupload.io/m8afmp).

The same select query is working for a different table in the same db, schema.

Note that this table (schema_migrations) was created via golang code using snowflake library for golang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snowflake's object identifiers are case-sensitive. Your table [created from Go](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifiers-syntax.html#third-party-tools-and-case-insensitive-identifier-resolution) has been created with a [double-quoted table name identifier](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifiers-syntax.html#double-quoted-identifiers), and thus appears as lower-case in your screenshot.

Therefore, to query it, you must explicitly specify a lower-case name:

```sql
SELECT * FROM UTIL_DB.PUBLIC."schema_migrations";
```

Unquoted identifier names are [treated as upper-case](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifiers-syntax.html#label-identifier-casing) and [will not match](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifiers-syntax.html#double-quoted-identifiers) identifiers that were double-quoted. Quoting the relevant documentation portions that speak of this:

> When an identifier is unquoted, it is stored and resolved in uppercase.
>
> When an identifier is double-quoted, it is stored and resolved exactly as entered, including case.

And,

> If an object is created using a double-quoted identifier, when referenced in a query or any other SQL statement, the identifier must be specified exactly as created, including the double quotes.
>
> Failure to include the quotes might result in an Object does not exist error (or similar type of error).